# Python module installed and can be run in terminal but not in file

Tags: python, module, linux-mint

My issue is that i am able to import a python module in the terminal using the shell but when i import the same module in a file, i get an error.
This is the message i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dalcoy/Desktop/Projects/Scripts/something.py", line 1, 
in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u 
"/home/dalcoy/Desktop/Projects/Scripts/something.py"]
[dir: /home/dalcoy/Desktop/Projects/Scripts]
[path:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

this is the program:

```
import pygame
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are they using the same python version?

Answer (score 0):

You must install the module first in order to use it in your script. Run `py -m pip install pygame` to install the module. Then it will work fine in your script

Answer (score 0):

Check what kind of python version you're using, as the python shell might be 2.7 and when you try to launch it as a script from a file it could be interpreted by different python version, for e.g. python3 which doesn't have this module installed.

To check:

```
# which python
```

or

```
# which python3
```

You can also call a file like this to specify which python version you want:

```
# python3 /path/to/file.py
```

or

```
# python /path/to/file.py
```

You can also make a file an executable using

```
# chmod +x /path/to/file.py
```

And adding hashbang to the first line of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

To then be able to run a python script like this:

```
# ./my_script.py
```

Here you can read on managing packets with pip for different versions:

[pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It turned out that I was using python 3 instead of python 2. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: you're welcome, you can accept it as an answer to help the others :)